# Why do the following two codes make different results?

Tags: caching, profiling

I have two similar codes below.

**1st code:**

```
unsigned long size = 256*1024*1024;
unsigned long stride = 256;
void *array = (void*)malloc(size);
for (unsigned long off = 0; off < size; off+=stride) {
    *(unsigned int*)(array+off) = off+stride;
}
*(unsigned int*)(array+off)=0;
int i=10000000;
struct timeval start, end;
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
while (i>=1) {
    offset = *(unsigned int*)(array+off);
    i--;
}
gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
*(volatile unsigned int*)(array+offset);
printf("%.2f\n", (end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000000+(end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec));
```

**2nd code:**

```
unsigned long size = 256*1024*1024;
unsigned long stride = 256;
void *array = (void*)malloc(size);
for (unsigned long off = 0; off < size; off+=stride) {
    *(unsigned int*)(array+off) = off+stride;
}
*(unsigned int*)(array+off)=0;
int i=10000000;
struct timeval start, end;
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
#define ONE offset = *(unsigned int*)(array+off);
#define FIVE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE
#define TEN FIVE FIVE
#define FIFTY TEN TEN TEN TEN TEN
#define HUNDRED FIFTY FIFTY
while (i>=1000) {
    HUNDRED
    HUNDRED
    HUNDRED
    HUNDRED
    HUNDRED
    HUNDRED
    HUNDRED
    HUNDRED
    HUNDRED
    HUNDRED
    i-=1000;
}
gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
*(volatile unsigned int*)(array+offset);
printf("%.2f\n", (end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000000+(end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec));
```

**Question**

The only difference between two codes is "while loop."
They both measure the elapsed time for while loop.

The first code makes a result of 779,851,000 ns and the second code makes a result of 1,624,344,000 ns. (2.1 times larger)

I thought this difference comes from L1-i cache misses, so I measured L1-i cache misses with perf.

However, the L1-i cache miss of the first code is 34,541 and the L1-i cache miss of the second code is 43,078. (1.2 times larger)

This result cannot completely explain the difference in elapsed times for while loop.

What makes the big difference between elapsed times of two codes?

Is there anything that I miss?